# Loading custom directive dynamically by assigning it to controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to load my custom directive dynamically on click of a button. On click, I would make an AJAX call to get the directive html. Once i get a response, i compile that response and assign it to a controller scope variable. I was expecting that the corresponding template of the custom directive to display properly but that is not the case. Please help.

Below is a sample of code which has the same issue.

In my HTML file:

```
<body ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="DemoController as DemoCtrl">
 <div ng-bind-html="test">
 <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="DemoCtrl.getDirective()">Click to get directive</md-button>
</body>
```

My module and corresponding controller / directive:

```
angular.module('sampleApp',['ngMaterial'])

        .directive('test',function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<B>Hello World</B>'
            };
        })

        .controller('DemoController', function($compile,$scope,$sce) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.getDirective = function(){
                //Here I make a service call to get the directive. In this case I get a response as <test></test>
                var directiveCode = $compile("<test></test>");
                var directiveHTML = directiveCode($scope);
                $scope.test = $sce.trustAsHtml(directiveHTML);
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You could add `.html()` to `directiveHTML` to get the html of the compiled template. Then it should work. Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/29g4597s/). ($scope.$apply() is not needed in the fiddle)

Comment: Thanks @AWolf. It worked. But my custom directive is much more complex than what I have shown here.  I actually have a nested custom directive inside <test> in this case. Would that make a difference?

Comment: I think that should also work. But that depends on your directive definition object. With `transclude: true` you can make nested directives. See updated fiddle (same link from above).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
angular.module('sampleApp',['ngMaterial'])

        .directive('test',function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<B>Hello World</B>'
            };
        })

        .controller('DemoController', function($compile,$scope,$sce) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.getDirective = function(){
                //Here I make a service call to get the directive. In this case I get a response as <test></test>
                var directiveCode = $compile("<test></test>");
                var directiveHTML = directiveCode($scope);
                console.log(directiveHTML.html());
                $scope.test = $sce.trustAsHtml(directiveHTML.html());
                //$scope.$apply();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help @Awolf and @wasiq. Your code snippet worked fine.

Issue in my case was that i was assigning the template of the directive to the controller scope even before the AJAX call has been resolved.  Because of that, i was not getting the directive's template in the DOM. Now i moved the scope variable assignment inside the success block and this fixed the issue.